# What is the regular expression to the whether the string is Number(including decimals) or not?

Tags: java, regex, numbers

Let us assume following are the strings i'm having.
1234 and 123.45 or 123.5687
I have to check whether above things are numbers or not. It's should return true decimals too.

Comment: Here's the regex used in the Scanner class for floats/doubles, though it encompasses much more than you require: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Scanner.java#Scanner.buildFloatAndDecimalPattern%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

You need anchors to disable partial matching.

Comment: i'm getting error while executing. Can u write this as   regex="^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$";

Comment: @BNarasimha use `^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$`

Comment: this is not not working for three digits after decimal point. Ex: 2.365

Answer (score 1):

`myString.matches("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?");` will check for both integers and decimal numbers.

Comment: Hi. It's checks for decimal . It's not working for Intergers.

Comment: @BNarasimha - I edited my answer, there was a typo.. Now it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

This will return true if there are only numbers or numbers with only one decimal that has at least one number after the decimal. It will also work for negative numbers. `(^\\-?\\d*\\.?\\d+$)`

Comment: I have stored ^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$ in DB column. Now iam fetching that from DB and storing that in one string variable. Now verifying whether it is a number or not it;s showing wrong answer.

Comment: After fetching form DB i think so its not working as a Regular Expression.

Comment: Before inserting into db need to sql escape the string by replacing all the '\' with '\\'. This way the sql doesn't misunderstand and think you are escaping the characters following the '\'

Comment: Instead of     ^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$
try inserting this     ^\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?$

Comment: one more doubt. how can i verify whether a number is decimal or not with out using Regular Expression. Please let me know if any methods are there.

Comment: If you know its a number but not sure what type, you can convert to String and use .indexOf (".") > -1. Alternatively,  you could use Math.round method and compare to original value

Comment: It's working fine for positive numbers. Then what about negative number.

Comment: Update my answer. Or if you are using other expression,  can insert \-? In front of expression.

Comment: So you can replace ^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$ with this ^\-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$

Comment: Well since its java it needs to be this ^\\-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$